# Assign values from one member of a group to another in R

Tags: r, plyr, reshape

I have height data for siblings nested in families of two siblings each:

```
   ID family sibling height
1   1      1       1    103
2   2      1       2    100
3   3      2       1    102
4   4      2       2     98
5   5      3       1    104
6   6      3       2    100
7   7      4       1     98
8   8      4       2     94
9   9      5       1     95
10 10      5       2    111
11 11      6       1    112
12 12      6       2    113
```

Using R, in each family, I would like to create a new variable with each sibling assigned the value of his or her co-sibling's height, like so:

```
   ID family sibling height cosib_height
1   1      1       1    103          100
2   2      1       2    100          103
3   3      2       1    102           98
4   4      2       2     98          102
5   5      3       1    104          100
6   6      3       2    100          104
7   7      4       1     98           94
8   8      4       2     94           98
9   9      5       1     95          111
10 10      5       2    111           95
11 11      6       1    112          113
12 12      6       2    113          112
```

It is easy to aggregate across the two members of the family, for instance to find the mean height of each family, but I haven't been able to figure out how to assign each individual his or her co-sibling's height.

I suspect it can be done using the reshape or plyr packages, but I have so far had no luck in doing so.

EDIT: Another complication is that in the real data I am working with, occasionally one or both siblings in a family will be missing height data (NA for height). Any solutions that will still work when height is sometimes missing would be very much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: What happens when one height is NA? Both NA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is called dat this works:

```
dat$cosib_height <- unlist(lapply(split(dat$height, dat$family), rev))

##    ID family sibling height cosib_height
## 1   1      1       1    103          100
## 2   2      1       2    100          103
## 3   3      2       1    102           98
## 4   4      2       2     98          102
## 5   5      3       1    104          100
## 6   6      3       2    100          104
## 7   7      4       1     98           94
## 8   8      4       2     94           98
## 9   9      5       1     95          111
## 10 10      5       2    111           95
## 11 11      6       1    112          113
## 12 12      6       2    113          112
```

A variant:

```
dat <- transform(dat, cosib_height = ave(height, family, FUN=rev))
```

Comment: @flodel why not throw it down as a second response?  It's better.

Comment: well, they're very similar and you deserved the points for grouping and applying `rev`.

Comment: Both of those solutions work splendidly! Thank you both! I'm sorry my rep is still too low to up vote, but I have marked this as a best answer.